# Is there any working android example of kurento one2one call?

Tags: webrtc, kurento

I have installed Kurento in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Server. And configured with public stun server. The tutorials given by kurento are working fine.

But I need a android app, to have one2one video call.

There are few example in github.

But none of them are working for me in android studio.

https://github.com/billyriantono/kurento-android-client

which is based on

https://github.com/MaxMaes/WebRTCTest

Both are not working, as they are based on old Kurento versions.

Is there any recent working example for kurento one2one call in android?

Comment: here is complete example
https://github.com/nubomedia-vtt/nubo-test

only you need to configure project. In case you need any help you can contact me

Comment: Hii @VivekPatel i am unable to connect video call by following "https://github.com/nubomedia-vtt/kurento-room-client-android", please help if possible.

Comment: @RahulJain ,what problem you are facing .if i know the error then only i can help you.

Comment: Hii Vivek Patel , problem is my sdp answer from web is not publishing at mobile end, i make call from app it come to web, when i accept i get sdp answer response from server which is not publishing at my master view plus my streaming is not visible at web end.